# Refer to first returned value of function in python

Tags: python, function

I want to refer to the first returned element of a function.

I have a function that returnes two values: x*2 and y*2.

In the next function, I want to refer to the first value. How is that done? An example of my attempt here:

```
def helper1(x,y):
    return x*2,y*2

def helper2(x,y):
    helper1(x,y)
    a = 2/helper1[0] #here I try to refer to the first element returned of helper1, but doesn't work :( 
    return a
```

any ideas?

Comment: `a, _ = helper1(...)`? `a = helper1(...)[0]`?

Comment: You need to assign the result of `helper1` to something before you try to reference it. Maybe something like `results = helper1(x,y)` and then you can do `a=2/results[0]` on the next line.

Comment: That is beside the point :P the code is obviously longer, I just want to know how to access the 1st returned value of a function. (answer to jonrsharpe). I want the a to be a = 2/(x*2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def helper1(x,y):
    return x*2, y*2

def helper2(x,y):
   a = 2/helper1(x, y)[0]   # how to access to the 1st value of helper1
   return a  # no idea of what is a

print(helper2(3, 4))
#0.3333333333333333
```

Comment: I removed the parameter a from the signature of the function... I think you mess up a bit the stuff... but you had the right intuitions

Comment: Yea dont worry,  I just made these functions fast as an example so I did not have to include my original program :)

Answer (score 1):

```
alpha, beta = helper1(x, y)
a = 2 / alpha
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped! :D

Comment: Yea ofc but it says I can't do it before 10 mins has passed :D

Answer (score 1):

You just stuck the function there instead of the result of the function.

Here I'm calling the function and getting the [0] before I divide. By the way, are you trying to assign the input a in a "pass by reference" style? Because I don't think that's going to work.

```
def helper1(x,y):
    return x*2,y*2

def helper2(a,x,y):
    a = 2/(helper1(x,y)[0]) #helper1(x,y)[0], not helper1[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
>>> def helper2(x, y):
...     tmp = helper1(x,y)    
...     a = 2/tmp[0]
```

Note that you need to store the result of calling `helper1(x,y)`. You can then acces the first element of that result biy indexing, e.g `tmp[0]`

Alternatively you could have done

```
...     a = 2/helper1(x,y)[0]
```

avoiding the use of a temporary variable